# "The article gives / leaves / creates the impression that ...". Are the three versions synonyms?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can I use the expressions marked in bold interchangeably in contexts similar to this example:

"The article **gives / leaves / creates / generates** the impression that a large crowd of people witnessed the experiment, when in reality only the inventor and his aide were present." ?

Comment: 'aid' should be spelt 'aide' in this context, https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aide

Comment: I made the change aid -> aide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

- Your question gives (me) the impression that you want to learn English.
- Your question leaves (me with) the impression that you're a good learner.
- Your question creates the impression that you have a curious mind.
- Your question generates the impression that you're learning English on a deep level.

"generates" is less common, but it can be used.

Comment: Thank you for your encouragement. The question is, whether I must use a pronoun or some other noun after gives or leaves like  "gives me"; "leaves me with". In my case, I don't really know to whom the text gives the impression. If it is not possible then creates \ generates  the impression remain my only choices.

Comment: You can remove it and still have it be correct. The object will be "implied".

Comment: In this case I have available in English all four versions written in the original text, in a foreign language.

Comment: This is true :)